# How to compare two 'time:Civil' values in Ballerina?

Tags: time, ballerina

I'm encountering an issue in Ballerina when trying to compare two times represented as `time:Civil`. The error message I'm receiving is `operator '<' not defined for 'ballerina/time:2.2.4:Civil' and 'ballerina/time:2.2.4:Civil'`.

Can someone guide me on how to properly compare two times in Ballerina and resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can not compare two `time:Civil` values using `<` or `>`. We can convert them into `time:Utc` and compare them as in the example below.

```php
import ballerina/time;
import ballerina/io;
    
public function main() returns time:Error? {
    time:Civil utcToCivil1 = check time:civilFromString("2017-01-01T00:00:00Z");
    time:Civil utcToCivil2 = check time:civilFromString("2017-02-01T00:00:00Z");
    
    time:Utc utcFromCivil1 = check time:utcFromCivil(utcToCivil1);
    time:Utc utcFromCivil2 = check time:utcFromCivil(utcToCivil2);
    
    io:println(utcFromCivil1 < utcFromCivil2);
}
```